# Calculating hours worked in the last 28 days

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a Firebird database which contains a table `Duty`:

| Date | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DATE | TIME | TIME |

This records the start and end times of my job. My goal is to count how many hours I've worked in the last 28 days (672 hours) from when the query was run. My starting point is:

```
SELECT
    SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, "Start", "End"))
FROM
    "Duty"
WHERE
    "Date" > DATEADD(-672, HOUR, TIMESTAMP 'NOW')
```

This gives me a `Token unknown - *,` error on line 6. Not sure what's wrong with the comma usage.

I also realise that my table has separate date and time columns, instead of a timestamp, which may cause some complications with the code above. Due to other data in the table, I can't use timestamps in it.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters to [`DATEADD`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-functions-datetime) are in the wrong order. It is either `DATEADD(<amount> <unit> TO <datetime>)` or `DATEADD(<unit>, <amount>, <datetime>)`. Given you use the comma-form, you need to put `HOUR` first.

As an aside, you should not use `TIMESTAMP 'NOW'`, use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (or `CURRENT_DATE` if you just need a DATE), or if you really must, `CAST('NOW' AS TIMESTAMP)`. `TIMESTAMP 'NOW'` no longer works in Firebird 4.0 or higher.

In other words, use:

```sql
DATEADD(HOUR, -672, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

However, if you want 28 days ago, why not just use

```sql
DATEADD(DAY, -28,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: I see where I went wrong. When I looked up the documentation, the first method was `<amount> <unit> TO <datetime>` while the second was `<unit>, <amount>, <datetime>`. Was easy to mix the order up. As for using `NOW` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, I had assumed they were the same.  Having a read of it, there's some minor differences. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: As for using hours or days, does it make a difference when I'm looking to ensure it's a rolling 28 day period? If not, then `DAY` would be better for code readability

Comment: @hiigaran They are nearly the same, except `'NOW'` will be reevaluated every time, while `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will be evaluated once for a statement execution. The problem however is that the timestamp literal `TIMESTAMP 'NOW'` will no longer work in newer Firebird versions (it will only support "real" dates in that version), requiring you to either use a cast, or use one of the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `LOCALTIMESTAMP` expressions.

Comment: @hiigaran The only difference using HOUR vs DAY makes here is readability, though in Firebird 4.0 it might make a small difference when using a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE and crossing a DST change.

Comment: Righty. That wouldn't be relevant to me, so `DAY` it is!

Comment: Using timestamps also raise another problem: what to do if it is midday now? With the query in question the day will be completely ignored even if some hours were worked afternoon. @hiigaran

Comment: So if I ran the query, I wouldn't get exactly 28 days prior to query run? It would round up/down?

Comment: @hiigaran You need to tag a user if you want their response, otherwise they don't get notified (I get notified because this is below my answer). In any case, the point  
user13964273 is trying to make that if your use a timestamp, and you execute this at midday, then you get a timestamp at that exact same time 28 days earlier, while you might want it at 00:00 to get all results of that day.

Comment: Understood, cheers. Regarding the timestamp usage, that is actually what I want, as the jobs in question require that certain hours are not to be exceeded before the start time of the individual job. However, the other method might be something I'll keep in mind for other conditions I'm trying to make queries for. As I'm slowly improving my understanding of Firebird, I should be able to figure it out on my own without asking another question!