# Converting percentage value to text-based progress bar

Tags: sql, firebird

Further to a personal project outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74483884/calculating-hours-worked-in-the-last-28-days) previous question, I am looking to take a percentage value returned from a Firebird query and output an ASCII style progress bar, using characters such as ▓.

The code I have at the moment is shown below:

```
SELECT FIRST 1
    (
        SELECT
            SUM("Day") +
            SUM("Night")
        FROM
            "Duty"
        WHERE
            "Date" > DATEADD (DAY, -28, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    ) AS "Hours Last 28 Days",
    (
        SELECT
            SUM("Day") +
            SUM("Night")
        FROM
            "Duty"
        WHERE
            "Date" > DATEADD (DAY, -365, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    ) AS "Hours Last 365 Days"
FROM
    "Duty"
```

I'm using Libreoffice Base as a frontend, and putting together a form to display a large amount of information, some of which I'd like some graphical representations of. Ideally, I'd like to avoid using macros and code this purely through the query, so I was thinking I'd take the two values returned from this query, divide it by the maximum legal hours, and have an output of one ▓ character per percent (rounded to nearest whole number).

So if the limit for `Hours Last 365 Days` was 1000, then I'd need to select `"Hours Last 365 Days" / 1000 * 100 AS "365 Day Percentage"`, rounded to the nearest whole number, then run the code which displays this as the progress bar.

At the moment, the only method I know of is to use 100 nested `IIF` statements. I'm guessing I don't need to explain why that would be an issue. Is there a more elegant way of achieving the same outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`RPAD`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-rpad) (or [`LPAD`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-lpad)) for this. For example, for 20%:

```sql
select rpad('', 20, '▓') from rdb$database
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/_wOyUU-G

Depending on the exact form of query, you may need to wrap it in an explicit cast to ensure Firebird knows the eventual length of the string value (e.g. `cast(rpad('', percent, '▓') as varchar(100))`).

As an aside, I'd advise to read the Firebird 3.0 Language Reference, chapter [Built-in Scalar Functions](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-functions) if you're looking for functions. It is probably more efficient than asking a question each time.

Comment: I was able to put the entire original `SELECT` statement into the second parameter of `RPAD`. Interestingly, if I were to divide and multiply the hours from that statement, the output accuracy was reduced. That is, if the original `SELECT` gives me `551.2` hours and I wanted to do `551.2/1000*100`, the result ends up being `50.0`. I can fix that by replacing `/1000*100` with just `/10`. For the purposes of my question, this is answered, and I have that workaround, but for future use, what causes that issue?

Comment: @hiigaran `551.2/1000` is a division between fixed point precision numbers, one with scale 1 and another with scale 0. The scale of the result is the addition of the scale of both operands, so in this case, the scale is 1, so `551.2/1000 = 0.5`. `0.5 * 100` is multiplication with fixed point precision numbers, with scale 1 and scale 0, the resulting scale is also 1, `0.5 * 100 = 50.0`. You could use `1000.0` to add one more scale (`551.2/1000.0 = 0.55`), or you could use `1000e0` to make it a double precision calculation instead.

Comment: On the other hand, `551.2/10` also is division between a scale 1 and scale 0, with result in scale 1: `551.2/10 = 55.1`.